# Why my router UI in angular.js is not working as expected?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

my problem is that the routing is not working as expected, here is my code :

```
$urlRouterProvider.
otherwise('/list');

$stateProvider.
state('home', {
abstract: true,
views: {
    'header': {
        templateUrl: 'partials/header.html',
        controller: 'HeaderController'
    },
    'breadcrumb': {
        templateUrl: 'partials/breadcrumb.html',
        controller: function($scope) {
            $scope.breadcrumb = ['Home', 'Library', 'Data'];
        }
    },
    'sidebar': {
        templateUrl: 'partials/sidebar.html'
    }
}

}).
state('home.list', {
url: '/list',
views: {
    'main@': {
        templateUrl: 'partials/list.html',
        controller: 'ListController'
    }
 }
 }).
state('home.details', {
url: '/details/:id',
views: {
    'main@': {
        templateUrl: 'partials/details.html',
        controller: 'DetailsController'
    }         
}
});
```

in my index i have this :

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <!-- SideBar -->
        <div ui-view="sidebar" class="col-xs-3 sidebar"></div>
        <!-- /.SideBar -->


        <div class="col-xs-8">
            <!-- Breadcrumb -->
            <div ui-view="breadcrumb" class="pull-right"></div>
            <!-- /.Breadcrumb -->

            <!-- Main Content -->
            <div ui-view="main"></div>
            <!-- /.Main Content -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

the problem is that the first time i enter the app (the otherwise works fine) but when trying to click on a hyperlink with details/id i get this error : Error: Could not resolve 'details' from state 'home.list', i'm a little bit confused right now !!!

Comment: Where is the code for the link you are clicking? I don't see it in the index template you are referring to.

Comment: it's in my list.html 

<table class="table table-hover">
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th>Name</th>
   <th>Address</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr ng-repeat="person in persons">
   <td><a ui-sref="details({id: persons.indexOf(person)})">{{person.name}}</a></td>
   <td>{{person.address}}</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>

Comment: I think it should be `main@home.list` & `main@home.details`

Comment: already done, in this case it does not work at all !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `home.details` in ui-sref instead of just `details`.

I have an example working in [this Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/xJSBaE?p=preview).

Answer (score 0):

```
    <table class="table table-hover"> 
<thead> 
<tr> 
<th>Name</th> 
<th>Address</th> 
</tr> 
</thead> 
<tbody> 
<tr ng-repeat="person in persons"> 
<!-- <td><a ui-sref="details({id: persons.indexOf(person)})">{{person.name}}</a></td> -->

 <td><a ui-sref="home.details({id: persons.indexOf(person)})">{{person.name}}</a></td> 
    <td>{{person.address}}</td> 
    </tr> 
    </tbody> 
    </table>
```